# form constructor and annotation builder

Tags: forms, annotations

I am in trouble with zf2 form annotation. The problem is:
a have a form with annotations with simple elements, but I need to add a fieldset to the form annotation. The fieldset contains some text elements. Until here I have no problem to create the form in the controller using the annotationBiulder and CreateForm method.
But if I want to pass some parameters to the constructor fieldset, it is not possible to call the fieldset with the annotation. 
Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

use for fieldset

- @Annotation\ComposedObject("Namespace/Entity/MyEntity")

see http://devblog.x2k.co.uk/using-the-composedobject-zend-framework-2-form-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a solution for my problem.
I have a form built with annotation and with a custom fieldset inside named MyFieldset

```
/**
 * @Form\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 * @Form\Name("MyForm")
 */

class MyForm {

 /**
 * @Form\Required(false)
 * @Form\Attributes({"type":"hidden"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Form\Required(true)
 * @Form\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Form\Options({"label":"Title"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Form\Validator({"name": "StringLength", "options": {"min":3, "max": 250}})
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @Form\Required(true)
 * @Form\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Form\Options({"label":"Description"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 */
protected $description;

/**
 * @Form\Required(false)
 * @Form\Type("Application\Form\MyFieldset")
 * @Form\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 * @Form\Options({"label":"Translations"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 */
protected $translations;
```

The MyFieldset class has a constructor needing an object parameter that I need to use to replace the for loop. I have tried various possible solutions to solve this issue, for instance using Service Locator injection implementing ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.

```
class MyFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

protected $obj;

public function __construct(SomeObject $obj) {

    parent::__construct('myfieldset');

    $this->obj = $em;
}

public function init() {

    for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {

        $object = new Element\Text();

        $object
            ->setAttribute('name', 'myfieldset_'.$i)
            ->setOptions(array('label' => 'Myfieldset'))
        ;//->setAttribute('required', true);

        $this->add($object);
    }
}

public function getInputFilterSpecification() {

    return array(
            /* 'name' => $this->getName(),
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
                    array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringToLower'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                    array(
                                    'name' => 'String'
                            )
            ), */

    );
```